# No such column 'Email' on entity 'Task'.

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I have a SOQL query:

[Select Email From Task];

As far as I can tell from the object manager Email is a field on the Task object, however, I am getting this error:

'No such column 'Email' on entity 'Task'.'

How can I access the Email field on the Task object?

Answer (score 0):

Email fields value populates on Task based on whoid selected i.e. Contact or Lead while creating task. You need to make 2 soql queries, first to get whoid from Task and second on contact/lead based on object selected on Task. Sample query on contact would be `[Select Email from contact where id ='<whoid>']`

```
Lead record id starts with prefix '00Q' and Contact record id start with prefix '003'. you can check prefix (first 3 digit) of whoid from task query and based on prefix run 2nd query.
```

Let me know if this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you for your help. From your answer, I managed to figure out that the field can be accessed using Who.Email, Owner.Email, What.Email.

Comment: Please validate once if you able to get values using Who.Email, Owner.Email, What.Emai. SOQL will not give you an error.

Comment: Yeah I checked it, works well. Thanks again for your help!